# Nested tree list with a directive in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble with a nested list Directive using Angular.  Each time I try to run my code the browser crashes when I call the directive recursively.

I'd like to output a new list item if the `children` property in the data has items in it.

Here's a fiddle to my code, I removed the directives call to itself so that it does not crash the browser.  http://jsfiddle.net/8p3bf4ec/

JS:

```
var jsonData = {
    "title": "Home",
    "author": "Mary",
    "children": [
        {
            "title": "Clothing",
            "author": "Robert",
            "children": [
                {
                    "title": "Shirts",
                    "author": "Bill",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Electronics",
            "author": "William",
            "children": []
        }
    ]
};

angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').directive('itemList', function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: 'itemListTemplate.html',
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.nodes = jsonData;
            console.log($scope.nodes);
        }
    };
});
```

Template:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

    <item-list></item-list>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="itemListTemplate.html">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="node in nodes">
                {{node.title}}
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Removed this because it makes the browser crash
        <item-list></item-list>
        -->
    </script>

</div>
```

Comment: Usng `ng-repeat="node in nodes"`, the root of your `jsonData` should probably be an array -- `var jsonData = [ { ... } ];` Otherwise, it's iterating the root object's values -- `"Home"`, `"Mary"`, etc.

Comment: render your directive element on some condition `<item-list ng-ig="expression"></item-list>` , as your calling it inside your template recursively..and directive is compiling infinite times..that's why browser is getting hanged..

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I'd like it to be an array at the root but it's not and unfortunately it's not something I have control over.

Comment: @Mdd The directive could itself wrap the data in an Array -- `$scope.nodes = angular.isArray(jsonData) ? jsonData : [ jsonData ];`

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks, I had not realize that.  I'm just starting out with Angular and directives are still pretty new to me but it seems like a good way to re-make a reuseable list.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you infinitely iterate through jsonData instead of each node's children. I guess you should not use directive here at all because there is not much logic and it adds unnecessary complexity. Just use ng-include instead of directive. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tree-view">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <!-- any data you want to display from item itself -->
        <div
            ng-if="item.children && item.children.length"
            ng-init="items=item.children"
            ng-include="'tree-view'">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</script>

<div class="tree-view" ng-include="'tree-view'"></div>
```